# Connecting an Android Virtual Deice with a real device

Tags: android-emulator, wifi-direct

I want to test an android application using WiFi-Direct, and i want to ask if i can connect an virtual device created with VirtualBox with my real device android.  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes,wifi-direct is in VBox settings

Comment: must the real device be connected to the pc with USB, or it can connect with the AVD without?  thanks in advance.

Comment: your are simulating wifi_direct ..ie two vbox images running at same time

Comment: no, i want to test one vbox with my real device, and i want to know if it's possible or no ?